# Tagging products or setting as private in bulk is taking very long in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, tagging, bulkupdate

Tagging products or setting  as private in bulk is taking very long in Woocommerce (about 2 minutes for 100 products). Is this normal? Or is it because Wordpress is inefficient? I've noticed that when setting a page of products as private instead of running a query like this UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_status` = 'private' WHERE `wp_posts`.`ID` = 26183; for each product, it seems to update everything about each product of the batch (status, category etc, even though I specifically just changed the status to private when bulk editing and left everything unchanged).

I just did standard bulk editing from the admin backend and i wasn't expecting it to be so slow.